# How to get catch2 to print the compared C-style string's contents?

Tags: unit-testing, string-comparison, catch2

I'm using catch2 (latest release - 2.13.6 as of this moment), and in my testcases I have a bunch of checks similar to the following:

```
CHECK(!strcmp(my_str, "some literal string here"));
```

where the literal is different for each testcase and obviously so is `my_str`'s contents.

When such a check fails, what I get on the output is the following:

```
/path/to/test_source_file.cpp:123: FAILED:
  CHECK( !strcmp(my_str, "some literal string here") )
with expansion:
  false
```

but I don't get the stirng within `my_str` printed out. What's the best way to get the above to print (some of) the contents of `my_str` as well?

Notes:

- You may not assume `my_str` is null-terminated.
- Code must relatively succinct.
- I would rather not convert anything to an `std::string`, but if you must do that, I'm not ruling it out.

Answer (score 0):

My own hacky solution is the following:

```
#define PRINTING_CHECK(expected_, actual_)           \
do {                                                 \
  INFO( "actual_   = " << '"' << actual_   << '"');  \
  INFO( "expected_ = " << '"' << expected_ << '"');  \
  CHECK(!strcmp(actual_, expected_));                \
} while (false)                                      \
```

but I was hoping there might be something more elegant.